# MongoDB is not marshaling a value before storing it

Tags: go, bson, mgo

I'm using a custom JSON marshaller/unmarshaller for a mapping between integers and strings in Go. The problem is that values are being stored in the database as integers instead of strings. In the example below, I would expect this to be stored in the MongoDB database:

```
{ "_id" : "id123", "desc" : "Red Delicious", "value" : "apple" }
```

Instead I get:

```
{ "_id" : "id123", "desc" : "Red Delicious", "value" : 1 }
```

As the test shows, marshalling and unmarshalling are working fine. What's going on?

Here's an example as a Go test (save to unmarshal_test.go and "go test").

```
package testunmarshal

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
    "encoding/json"
    mgo "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type Const int

const (
    Apple Const = 1
    Banana = 2
    Cherry = 4
)

type Record struct {
    Id string `bson:"_id" json:"id"`
    Desc string `bson:"desc" json:"desc"`
    Value Const `bson:"value" json:"value`
}

func (intValue Const) Code() string {
    switch intValue {
    case Apple: return "apple"
    case Banana: return "banana"
    case Cherry: return "cherry"
    }
    return "invalid"
}

func (intValue *Const) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) (err error) {
    switch string(data) {
    case `"apple"`: 
        *intValue = Apple
    case `"banana"`:
        *intValue = Banana
    case `"cherry"`:
        *intValue = Cherry
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("Invalid fruit %s", data)
    }
    return nil
}

func (intValue *Const) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`"%s"`, intValue.Code())), nil
}

func TestMarshalJSON(t *testing.T) {
    var orig = Record {
        Id: "id456",
        Desc: "Cavendish",
        Value: Banana,
    }

    var copy Record

    bytes, err := json.Marshal(&orig)

    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Marshal failed: %s", err.Error())
        return
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &copy)

    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Unmarshal failed: %s", err.Error())
        return
    }

    if orig.Value != copy.Value {
        t.Errorf("Expected %d=%s, got %d=%s", orig.Value, orig.Value.Code(), copy.Value, copy.Value.Code())
    }
}

func TestMarshalBSON(t *testing.T) {
    var orig = Record {
        Id: "id456",
        Desc: "Cavendish",
        Value: Banana,
    }

    var copy Record

    bytes, err := bson.Marshal(&orig)

    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Marshal failed: %s", err.Error())
        return
    }

    err = bson.Unmarshal(bytes, &copy)

    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Unmarshal failed: %s", err.Error())
        return
    }

    if orig.Value != copy.Value {
        t.Errorf("Expected %d=%s, got %d=%s", orig.Value, orig.Value.Code(), copy.Value, copy.Value.Code())
    }
}

func TestMongo(t *testing.T) {
    var rec1 = Record {
        Id: "id123",
        Desc: "Red Delicious",
        Value: Apple,
    }
    var rec2 Record

    sess, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")

    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf(err.Error())
        return
    }

    db := sess.DB("test")

    if db == nil {
        t.Fatal("Failed to connect to database")
        return
    }

    col := db.C("fruit")

    if col == nil {
        t.Fatal("Failed to open collection")
        return
    }

    // defer col.DropCollection()

    err = col.Insert(&rec1)

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal("Failed to insert: %s", err.Error())
        return
    }

    err = col.Find(bson.M{}).One(&rec2)

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal("Failed to retrieve stored object: %s", err.Error())
        return
    }

    if rec1.Value != rec2.Value {
        t.Errorf("Expected %d=%s, got %d=%s", rec1.Value, rec1.Value.Code(), rec1.Value, rec2.Value.Code())
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Added more tests to demonstrate that marshalling and unmarshalling are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bson encoder does not use the JSON marshaling interfaces. Implement the [Getter](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Getter) interface:

```
func (intValue Const) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    return intValue.Code(), nil
}
```

You will also want to implement the [Setter](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Setter) interface.

```
func (intValue *Const) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) error {
    var data int
    if err := raw.Unmarshal(&data); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    switch data {
    case `"apple"`: 
        *intValue = Apple
    case `"banana"`:
        *intValue = Banana
    case `"cherry"`:
        *intValue = Cherry
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("Invalid fruit %s", data)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: If you wouldn't mind adding a note on the Setter interface as well, I'd be happy to mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks!